# Removing Item from JPA OneToManyList before Persisting

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

This is about a JSF + JPA application.

Bill and BillItem are two entities with Bilateral OneToMany relationship with cascadeType=all in a JPA application.

When the use clicks a new Bill, a new Bill object is create. User then fill properties of a BillItem like name and quantity and click the Add to Bill button, so that BillItem is added to the list of BillItems in the Bill Object. User interface is updated with Datatable linked to the bill.billItems.

After adding one or more billItems to the Bill, the user click the settle button where the bill object is persisted.

The issue is that it is not possible to remove billItem from the list. Always the first item is removed. How can I get the required billItem from the list ?

Code of Bill Entity

```
@Entity
public class Bill implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bill", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<BillItem> billItems = new ArrayList<>();

...
..

}
```

Code for BillItem Entity

```
@Entity
public class BillItem implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    Bill bill;

....
...


@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {

    if (!(object instanceof BillItem)) {
        return false;
    }
    BillItem other = (BillItem) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Code for JSF Managed Bean

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SaleController implements Serializable {

    private BilledBill bill;
    BillItem billItem;

    public void removeItem(){
        if(removingItem==null){
            UtilityController.addErrorMessage("Select one to remove");
            return;
        }
        getBill().getBillItems().remove(removingItem);
    }

    public String newSaleBill() {
        fillAvailableStocks();
        listBillsToSettle();
        clearBill();
        clearBillItem();
        printPreview = false;
        bill = null;
        return "sale";
    }

    public void settle() {
....
        saveBill();
        UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("Successfully Billed");
    }


    public void addItem() {
......
        getBill().getBillItems().add(billItem);
        calTotal();
        clearBillItem();
    }




    public void saveBill() {
        bill.setBillType(BillType.SaleToCustomer);
        getBill().setInstitution(getSessionController().getInstitution());
        getBill().setDepartment(getSessionController().getDepartment());
        getBill().setStaff(getSessionController().getLoggedUser().getStaff());

        getBill().setDeptId(getBillNumberBean().departmentBillNumberGenerator(getSessionController().getDepartment(), BillType.SaleToCustomer, BillNumberSuffix.SB));
        getBill().setInsId(getBillNumberBean().institutionBillNumberGenerator(getSessionController().getInstitution(), BillType.SaleToCustomer, BillNumberSuffix.SB));
        getBill().setRepId(getBillNumberBean().institutionBillNumberGenerator(getSessionController().getLoggedUser().getStaff(), BillType.SaleToCustomer, BillNumberSuffix.SB));
        getBill().setToInstitution(getSessionController().getInstitution());
        getBill().setToDepartment(getSessionController().getDepartment());
        getBill().setCreatedAt(new Date());


        getBill().setBillDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        getBill().setCreater(getSessionController().getLoggedUser());
        getBillFacade().create(getBill());
    }


    public BilledBill getBill() {
        if (bill == null) {
            bill = new BilledBill();
            getBillFacade().create(bill);

        }
        return bill;
    }


    public BillItem getBillItem() {
        if (billItem == null) {
            billItem = new BillItem();
        }
        return billItem;
    }

    public void setBillItem(BillItem BillItem) {
        this.billItem = BillItem;
    }


    public BillItem getRemovingItem() {
        return removingItem;
    }

    public void setRemovingItem(BillItem removingItem) {
        this.removingItem = removingItem;
    }



}
```

JSF Page

```
            <h:panelGrid columns="5">
                <h:outputLabel value="Select Item"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Qty (kg)"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Rate"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Value"/>
                <h:outputLabel value=""/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="acItem" converter="stockCon" value="#{saleController.billItem.stock}" var="vt"   >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{saleController.availableStock}" var="ast" itemValue="#{ast}" itemLabel="#{ast.itemBatch.item.name}" ></f:selectItems>
                    <p:column >
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{vt.itemBatch.item.name}" ></h:outputLabel>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column >
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{vt.stock}" ></h:outputLabel>
                    </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:inputText id="txtQty" value="#{saleController.billItem.qty}"   styleClass="normalNoBox" >
                    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="acItem txtQty " render="" listener="#{saleController.calValueFromRate()}"></f:ajax>
                </p:inputText>  
                <p:inputText id="txtRate" value="#{saleController.billItem.netRate}"   styleClass="normalNoBox" >
                    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="acItem txtQty txtRate" render="lblVal" listener="#{saleController.calValueFromRate()}" ></f:ajax>
                </p:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel id="lblVal" value="#{saleController.billItem.netValue}"  styleClass="normalNoBox" ></h:outputLabel>
                <p:commandButton value="Add Item" action="#{saleController.addItem}" ajax="false" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">                        
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:dataTable var="ph" value="#{saleController.bill.billItems}" id="itemList">  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputLabel value="Sale Items" ></h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>  
            <p:column headerText="Item Name" style="width:30%">  
                <h:outputLabel id="item" value="#{ph.item.name}"  >
                </h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Qty (kg)" style="width:20%">                     
                <h:outputLabel id="qty" value="#{ph.qty}"  >
                </h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Rate" style="width:20%">                     
                <h:outputLabel id="itemRate" value="#{ph.grossRate}"  >
                </h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Value" style="width:20%">                     
                <h:outputLabel id="itemVal" value="#{ph.grossValue}"  >
                </h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>  
             <p:column headerText="Remove" style="width:20%">                     
                 <h:commandButton value="Remove" action="#{saleController.removeItem()}" >
                     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{saleController.removingItem}" value="#{ph}" ></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                 </h:commandButton>
            </p:column>  

        </p:dataTable>  
    </p:panel>
```

Comment: Please show in your question the JSF markup element that binds to the `saleController.removingItem` property.

Comment: Thanks. Added as an edit.

Comment: Does BillItem override `public boolean equals(Object)`?

Comment: You haven't included the code for `Bill.getBillItemsOut()`, but I notice that the dataTable is populated by `getBillItemsOut()`, while the removeItem method modifies `getBillItems()` and not `getBillItemsOut()`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: I have three lists. BillItems, BillItemsIn, BillItemsOut, I wanted only to show parts related to BillItems, but mistakenly added wrong code set. I will correct that. Thanks.